# int8_t variable is always 0 in C language

Tags: c

I'm learning C language by myself.

I wrote the following code and executed it.

Unexpectedly the "first" variable was 0, though I inputted 4.

Could you explain me why this happens and how to fix this?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
        int8_t first;
        printf("Fist parameter:");
        scanf("%d", &first);

        int8_t second;
        printf("Second parameter:");
        scanf("%d", &second);

        printf("%d * %d == %d\n", first, second, first * second);
        return 0;
}
```

Expected:

```
Fist parameter:4
Second parameter:5
4 * 5 == 20
```

Actual:

```
Fist parameter:4
Second parameter:5
0 * 5 == 0
```

Comment: Turn on warnings for your compiler and pay attention to them.

Comment: Actually, that's not a duplicate. It's not a question of "what format specifier to use for int8", it's a much more interesting "why does it work this way" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `%d` format with `scanf`. `%d` assumes that the pointer it's used with points to an `int`, which is generally a 32-bit value (although it can be different sizes on different architectures). An `int8_t` is a one-byte value. Now, many computers these days are based on the Intel x86 family of processors, which is a "small-endian" architecture, meaning that the low-order part of a value stored from a register into memory goes into the low-order address of the block of memory (generally 4 bytes) where it's stored. Thus, when your program stored the value of 5 into `second` it was really storing **four bytes** of data, which in hex would be `0x00000005`. The `05` was stored into `second`, the low-order `00` was stored into `first` and the next two bytes of zeroes overlaid whatever was "next to" `first` in memory - so, congratulations, your program has a memory overwrite bug! It may not have been fatal, but it's there. :-)

As an experiment, try changing the types of `first` and `second` to `int`. I'll bet it then works as expected.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change `int8_t` to `int`. Then this could work for you.